# How to define "this" type in a binded function

Tags: typescript, types

I have a question, lets say I have the following code

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {}

    func(fn: () => any) {
        fn.bind(this)()
    }
}
```

So in this scenario, how would I tell the `fn` function that `this` the type `MyClass` using typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first parameter of a function is named `this`, then the type of that parameter will be used as the type of `this`:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {}

    func(fn: (this: MyClass) => any) {
        fn.bind(this)()
    }
}
```

See [Declaring "this" in functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOAVrm)

Comment: And the `fn` function can use `this` without having to use it as a parameter?

Comment: @Artrix Yes; see the playground I linked where I have shown that `this` is correctly typed in the callback.